# Deploy vue.js Quasar App with Azure Portal

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-web-app-service, quasar-framework

I am trying to deploy my Quasar app through Azure Portal. I have created a web app service, connected my github repo through the Deployment centre, and ran the build and deploy github workflow successfully (note: my `npm run build` calls `quasar build` which the Quasar docs describe). When I use FileZilla to access my server, I see my entire app along with the dist/spa folder under `site/wwwroot` so I believe the build worked correctly. Unfortunately, when I try to access my app through the browser, I am welcomed with the default Azure webapp page rather than my app.

[Default Azure WebApp Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3s5r.png)

I am unsure why my files are not being served. I have deployed a very simple Nuxt.js app in the past using the same approach and managed to deploy it relatively quickly. Perhaps nuxt.js does something under the hood that I am not aware about.

Any leads will be greatly appreciated.